# TYPO3 new tab to custom extension

Tags: typo3

I write my own extension. I have the file tx_xyz_domain_model_abc.php
with following code:

```
'types' => [
    '1' => [
        'showitem' => '
            --div--;Article, title,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language, sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, 
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access, hidden, starttime, endtime,
    '],
],
```

so the first line is my new field. The other lines are TYPO3 defaults. A --div-- is a new tab. How can i add the media or general tab to my extension?
I've tried to add

```
--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
```

But there is no new tab. How can i do this?

Comment: It seems not to be in the ExtJS real. Could you remove the tag?

Comment: wich tag should i remove?

Comment: Did you have a new tab with name Article? If not it could be a cache problem. Deactivate and reactivate your extension.

Comment: Yes my Artticle Tab is there. Tabs for language and access too. But no tab for general TYPO3 stuff like header and header position.

Comment: remove the `ExtJS` tag

Answer (score 1):

`--palette--;` will insert a new palette (=grouped fields) to the current tab (-> [TCA ref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Palettes/Index.html)).

Without defining a tab, the fields are automatically put in a "General"-Tab at first position.

```
'types' => [
   '0' => [
      'showitem' => '
         hidden, title,
         --div--;LLL:EXT:examples/locallang_db.xml:tx_examples_product.images, image1, image2,
      '
   ],
],
```

For further tabs, you need to insert a "--div--;label"-value in the field list (-> [TCA ref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Types/Properties/Showitem.html?)):

```
'types' => [
   '0' => [
      'showitem' => '
         hidden, title,
         --div--;LLL:EXT:examples/locallang_db.xml:tx_examples_product.text, description, teaser,
         --div--;LLL:EXT:examples/locallang_db.xml:tx_examples_product.images, image1, image2,
      '
   ],
],
```

Comment: Even with 
`--div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general, general,`
there is no new tab with the general info. is it because i have own database fields?

Comment: Do you have a field named `general`? If that does not exist and no other field should be displayed in the tab, the tab won't be shown up (because it's empty).

Answer (score 0):

To show the core general tab in your extension is not possible. You wrote your own extension with your own data model. This is saved in db table  tx_xyz_domain_model_abc. But data in core are from table tt_content which has a separate TCA.

You can

1. Extend table tt_content with your extension. Then you can use fields from tt_content
2. Add fields like header in your extension and table